# Kubernetes - Job scheduling API

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to schedule Jobs in Kubernetes.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

The job can be created using the below command.

```
$ kubectl create -f ./cronjob.yaml
cronjob "hello" created
```

Is there any REST API using which the Job can be created from a Java client?

Thanks

Comment: `kubectl` is literally just a wrapper around a [REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/).

Comment: So, we can hit the rest end point directly. Is there any documentation on the REST end points for Job scheudling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The respective REST endpoint is described in [the official API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch). You will find the `CronJob` resource in the `batch/v1beta1` API group. To create a new `CronJob` resource, you'll need a POST call to the `/apis/batch/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/cronjobs` URL.

A respective HTTP request might look something like this:

```
POST /apis/batch/v1beta1/namespaces/default/cronjobs HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: ...
Authorization: ...
[other headers]

{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "some-cron"
  },
  "spec": {
    ...
  }
}
```

There are also older versions of the same resource, for example in the [`batch/v2alpha1` API group](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#cronjob-v2alpha1-batch). As a rule of thumb, I'd recommend using the newest API version available to you. Especially, do not rely on alpha APIs in production; they tend to deprecate pretty quickly between releases.

To create a `batch/v1beta1` CronJob using the Java client, have a look at the [`createNamespacedCronJob` method](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1beta1Api.md#createNamespacedCronJob) of the `io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.BatchV1beta1Api` class.

Comment: The URL to the API reference is outdated and points to 404. Here's a link to [API v1.17 reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch)

Comment: @suda Thanks for the hint! I've updated the link in the anwser and brought it up-to-date in a few other regards, as well.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Request

```
POST /apis/batch/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/cronjobs
```

You can take a look here for API overview: [cronjob-v1beta1-batch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch)

Add CronJob object in request Body.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "batch/v1beta1",
  "kind": "CronJob",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "hello"
  },
  "spec": {
    "schedule": "*/1 * * * *",
    "jobTemplate": {

    }
  }
}
```

Check here its spec: [writing-a-cron-job-spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#writing-a-cron-job-spec)

Part of **swagger.json**

```
"post": {
 "description": "create a CronJob",
 "consumes": [
  "*/*"
 ],
 "produces": [
  "application/json",
  "application/yaml",
  "application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf"
 ],
 "schemes": [
  "https"
 ],
 "tags": [
  "batch_v1beta1"
 ],
 "operationId": "createBatchV1beta1NamespacedCronJob",
 "parameters": [
  {
   "name": "body",
   "in": "body",
   "required": true,
   "schema": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/io.k8s.api.batch.v1beta1.CronJob"
   }
  }
 ],
 "responses": {
  "200": {
   "description": "OK",
   "schema": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/io.k8s.api.batch.v1beta1.CronJob"
   }
  },
  "201": {
   "description": "Created",
   "schema": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/io.k8s.api.batch.v1beta1.CronJob"
   }
  },
  "202": {
   "description": "Accepted",
   "schema": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/io.k8s.api.batch.v1beta1.CronJob"
   }
  },
  "401": {
   "description": "Unauthorized"
  }
 },
 "x-kubernetes-action": "post",
 "x-kubernetes-group-version-kind": {
  "group": "batch",
  "kind": "CronJob",
  "version": "v1beta1"
 }
}
```

See full [swagger.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/master/api/openapi-spec/swagger.json)